# How to automate the task of adding the training phrases to correct intent inside dialogflow using any nlp model

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

I have an agent on Dialogflow with some fixed number of intents. Currently whenever a phrase does not trigger an intent(i.e trigger a default intent), i manually add the phrase to some existing intent or create a new intent and add the phrase to it.
I want to automate this task of adding the new phrase to a particular intent using some machine learning, nlp classifier.

I have trained a intent classifier to classify the intent based on the phrase, but i am not really sure what my training data should be for this task.

Please refer to following diagram. The diagram shows the thing i want to achieve.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6VRHuxM7E5-7iBVu1uo5SmYZpf6y71l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the link of your diagram is not publically accessible

Comment: I have updated the link please refer to it now.